# The meaning of "planes and angles"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-usage

What is the meaning of this phrase in describing a person's face?

> He looks at me, and sees me looking. He has a French face, lean,
>   whimsical, all **planes and angles**, with creases around the mouth where
>   he smiles.

Answer (score 1):

*Plane* is used here in the geometrical sense of a flat surface. The man's face is so lean (thin) that it seems to be made up of flat surfaces and angles rather than curves.